# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable ----

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, data-science

My code has the following relevant line:

```py
import collections as Counter
```

It outputs the following:

```
TypeError                                
<ipython-input-13-8b716be54873> in <module>
----> 1 print(sorted(Counter(dataset['Best']).items()))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Downvoting because code is not formatted as code. If this is addressed, I'll remove downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant `from collections import Counter`.

Comment: yes thank you. solved